# React or React Native to start learning

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have to work on project which has mobile application as well as web development too.For Mobile Application Development React Native has chosen but for Web development React has chosen.

I am new to React and confused from where i have to start learning. It should be React or React Native?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: _"I am new to React and confused from where i have to start learning"_ - [react official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to first start learning React, and then move on to React Native as React Native builds on React, and assumes you are already familiar with it. As pointed out by Vucko, the official documentation is a great place for information, otherwise you are interested in reading a book instead, check out Learning React functional web development with react and redux by alex banks and eve porcello, this helped me figure out a lot of things, and also covers redux which you might be using in the future.